# Delete duplicate from json array

Tags: arrays, json, duplicates, unique

Code:

```
$decode = json_decode($get, TRUE);
    foreach($decode['List'] as $lst) {

    }
```

I have an array $lst, that looks like this:

```
"List":[{
    "Name":"Ivan",
    "Surname":"Petrov",
}, {
    "Name":"Ivan",
    "Surname":"Ivanov",
}, {
    "Name":"Andrey",
    "Surname":"Sidorov",
}]
```

And I need to remove the duplicates so that something like this remains (duplicate 'Name'):

```
"List":[{
    "Name":"Ivan",
    "Surname":"Petrov",
}, {
    "Name":"Andrey",
    "Surname":"Sidorov",
}]
```

Comment: How do you plan to do that filtering? PHP?

Comment: Yes, php. I need input: $lst, output $lst2, for example.

Comment: `$json = <<<JSON
[
{"a":"abc","b:":"10"},
{"a":"abd","b:":"12"},
{"a":"abc","b:":"14"},
{"a":"abe","b:":"15"},
{"a":"abf","b:":"16"},
{"a":"abg","b:":"17"},
{"a":"abg","b:":"19"}
]
JSON;

$json_array = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

$new_array = array();
$exists    = array();
foreach( $json_array as $element ) {
    if( !in_array( $element['a'], $exists )) {
        $new_array[] = $element;
        $exists[]    = $element['a'];
    }
}

print json_encode( $new_array );`

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](http://lodash.com):

```js
var list = [{
    "Name":"Ivan",
    "Surname":"Petrov",
}, {
    "Name":"Ivan",
    "Surname":"Ivanov",
}, {
    "Name":"Andrey",
    "Surname":"Sidorov",
}];

var noDupsList = _.uniq(list, 'Name');

alert(JSON.stringify(noDupsList));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I make that, cause I have array as $lst:

var = list;
list = $lst;

And new unique array var as $lstuniq

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a predefined function exists to achieve this.

But you apply a comparison by iterating and duplicate one can be removed from json using delete operator
Like 
delete x[0]